# Convert html to pdf using Python/Flask

Tags: python, pdf, flask, wkhtmltopdf, xhtml2pdf

I want to generate pdf file from html using Python + Flask. To do this, I use xhtml2pdf. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    pdf = StringIO()
    pdf = create_pdf(render_template('cvTemplate.html', user=user))
    pdf_out = pdf.getvalue()
    response = make_response(pdf_out)
    return response

def create_pdf(pdf_data):
    pdf = StringIO()
    pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(pdf_data.encode('utf-8')), pdf)
    return pdf
```

In this code file is generating on the fly. BUT! xhtml2pdf doesn't support many styles in CSS, because of this big problem to mark page correctly. I found another instrument(wkhtmltopdf). But when I wrote something like:

```
pdf = StringIO()
data = render_template('cvTemplate1.html', user=user)
WKhtmlToPdf(data.encode('utf-8'), pdf)
return pdf
```

Was raised error:

```
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

And my question is how to convert html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf (with generating file on the fly) in Flask?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The page need render, You can use pdfkit:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

Example in document.

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')  # Is your requirement?
```

Comment: Ok. This code works fine (excludind troubles with install wkhtmltopdf):
rendered_template = render_template('template.html', user=user) rendered_template = rendered_template.encode('utf-8')
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered_template, False, css='./static/styles.css')
return make_response(pdf)
Thanks!

Comment: but it is need install wkhtmlpdf

Comment: it is working in local .But not able to install in cpanel  (live server).How to install wkhtmlpdf in cpanel

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried with [Flask-WeasyPrint](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WeasyPrint/), which uses [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/)? There are good examples in their web sites so I don't replicate them here.

Comment: The install instructions looked intimidating because of package dependencies but ````pip install weasyprint```` took care of everything.

Comment: WeasyPrint cannot handle JavaScript.

Comment: WeasyPrint support CSS2.1 but have no mention of js support. So if js support is needed, as of now, I would say pypuppeteer may help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would assist anyone but my issue was capturing Bootstrap5 elements as a pdf. pdfkit did not do so and heres a work around on windows using html2image and PIL. This is limited and does not take a full page screenshot.

```
from html2image import Html2Image
from PIL import Image

try:
   hti.screenshot(html_file=C:\yourfilepath\file.html, save_as="test.png")

finally:
   image1 = Image.open(r'C:\yourfilepath\test.png')
   im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
   im1.save(r'C:\yourfilepath\newpdf.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    config =   pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\Program 
        Files\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe') 

    filename = "receipt.pdf"
    pdf = pdfkit.from_file('templates/receipt.html', False,configuration=config)
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
    return response
```

Comment: first download wkhtml externally and setup in your system then mention the path of that. don't forget to change "\bin" to "\\bin".